# Rで傾向スコアマッチングがうまくいきません

Tags: r

```
matched_data<-matchit(ope_timing~age+height+sex+weight+flag_anticoag_antiplatelet+flag_pulse+flag_icu+flag_hcu+BarthelIndex_adm_cat+cci_quanindex+jcsadm_1, data = H_pre, method = "nearest",  replace = TRUE, ratio = 1)
> match_data <- match.data(matched_data)
> match_data
```

`ope_timing` (0 or 1 の二値変数です) の介入変数と、各種共変量を用いて、上記の通り、傾向スコアマッチングとして解析すると、

```
# A tibble: 1,001 × 165
```

と１：１マッチングにも関わらず、奇数になるのはどうしてでしょうか？
原因ご教示ください。

また、マッチングしたペアだけの全項目を切り取って新しいExcelファイルに保存するにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？併せてご教示ください。宜しくお願い致します。